# A shopping list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a shopping list with two buttons: one for adding and one for removing list items. When the remove button is clicked the paragraph should display some text + the last removed item, but it should stop displaying text when there aren't any list items left.

I tried to write an an if else statement like `if $("li:last" == 0)` then stop displaying the text, but I don't know where to integrate it. Also I would like to create a second function for `removeBtn`, just like the first, but it seems that the code binds to the first function. Any tips on how to structure this, please ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    shoppingList(addBtn);
  });
  $("#removeBtn").click(function() {
    $(".info").html($("li:last").text())
    $("li:last").remove();
    $(".info").addClass("remove");
    $(".info").removeClass("correct");
    $(".info").removeClass("error");
  });
});

function shoppingList(addBtn) {
  var writtenItem = $("#writtenItem").val();
  var info = $(".info");
  if (writtenItem == 0) {
    info.addClass("error")
    info.removeClass("correct")
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.html("")
  } else {
    $("ul").append("<li>" + writtenItem + "</li>")
    $("ul li").addClass("list-item");
    info.html(writtenItem + ' <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    info.removeClass("error");
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.addClass("correct");
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.error:after {
  content: "You have to actually type something before adding it to the list."
}

.correct {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.correct:before {
  content: "Added new list item: "
}

.remove {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.remove:before {
  content: "Removed last list item: "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="writtenItem" placeholder="Write something here" value="">
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add to list">
<input type="button" id="removeBtn" value="Remove last item">
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">Apples</li>
  <li class="list-item">Oranges</li>
  <li class="list-item">Lemons</li>
</ul>
<p class="info"></p>
```

Later edit (what I'm trying to get) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
shoppingList(addBtn);
});
$("#removeBtn").click(function() {
shoppingList(removeBtn);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there are any `li` left in the list by using `length` , see snippet below

As for the second thing you said ( add a second function just like the first ) i don't really understand. please comment here about that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    shoppingList(addBtn);
  });
  $("#removeBtn").click(function() {
      removeList(removeBtn);
  });
 function removeList(removeBtn) {
  
    if ($("li").length > 0) {
      $(".info").html($("li:last").text())
      $("li:last").remove();
      $(".info").addClass("remove");
      $(".info").removeClass("correct");
      $(".info").removeClass("error");
    } else {
      $(".info").removeClass("remove").html("");
    }


}

function shoppingList(addBtn) {
  var writtenItem = $("#writtenItem").val();
  var info = $(".info");
  if (writtenItem == 0) {
    info.addClass("error")
    info.removeClass("correct")
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.html("")
  } else {
    $("ul").append("<li>" + writtenItem + "</li>")
    $("ul li").addClass("list-item");
    info.html(writtenItem + ' <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    info.removeClass("error");
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.addClass("correct");
  }
}
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.error:after {
  content: "You have to actually type something before adding it to the list."
}

.correct {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.correct:before {
  content: "Added new list item: "
}

.remove {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.remove:before {
  content: "Removed last list item: "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="writtenItem" placeholder="Write something here" value="">
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add to list">
<input type="button" id="removeBtn" value="Remove last item">
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">Apples</li>
  <li class="list-item">Oranges</li>
  <li class="list-item">Lemons</li>
</ul>
<p class="info"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine now. Regarding the second function, I was trying to make it look like the first one.I know it is hard to understand what I mean. I will edit my question.

Comment: @spr1x i edited my answer. This is the best you can do. You cannot call the function `shoppingList` with `removeBtn` and expect it to work differently. Your `shoppingList` function has code inside it that does what the ADD button does. So if you call it with `removeBtn` , the `removeBtn` will work just like the add button. Which you don't want. So you need a second function for this...like in my answer

Comment: I understand the logic now and it sounds silly, but i tought that shoppingList(addBtn) and shoppingList(removeBtn) are two different functions. I will never make this mistake again. Thank you again, Mihai.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the item, you can check if any more items remain and hide the info text if there aren't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    shoppingList(addBtn);
  });
  $("#removeBtn").click(function() {
    $(".info").html($("li:last").text());
    $("li:last").remove();
    $(".info").addClass("remove");
    $(".info").removeClass("correct");
    $(".info").removeClass("error");

    // Check if any items remain, remove the text if there arent
    if ($("li").length == 0) {
      $(".info").html("").removeClass("remove");
    }
  });
});

function shoppingList(addBtn) {
  var writtenItem = $("#writtenItem").val();
  var info = $(".info");
  if (writtenItem == 0) {
    info.addClass("error")
    info.removeClass("correct")
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.html("")
  } else {
    $("ul").append("<li>" + writtenItem + "</li>")
    $("ul li").addClass("list-item");
    info.html(writtenItem + ' <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    info.removeClass("error");
    info.removeClass("remove")
    info.addClass("correct");
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.error:after {
  content: "You have to actually type something before adding it to the list."
}

.correct {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.correct:before {
  content: "Added new list item: "
}

.remove {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.remove:before {
  content: "Removed last list item: "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="writtenItem" placeholder="Write something here" value="">
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add to list">
<input type="button" id="removeBtn" value="Remove last item">
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">Apples</li>
  <li class="list-item">Oranges</li>
  <li class="list-item">Lemons</li>
</ul>
<p class="info"></p>
```